# como guardar de un array solo ciertos valores

Tags: php

Hola queria pedirle ayuda ya que soy nuevo en php,como puedo hacer para guardar de este array en variables solo las fechas (no siempre las fechas se encuentran como en este caso en 'es:' o en 'es5:' pueden encontrase en cualquier)

```
Array ( [0] => es: 2014-09-30, es1:, es2:, es3:, es4:, es5:2019-09-23 ,es6:,es7: )
```

tendría que quedar algo así como:
variable1= 2014-09-30
variable2= 2019-09-23

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: que has intentado hasta ahora? asi de primeras parece que quieres eliminar del array aquellas que no tienen valores, eso lo puedes hacer con `array_filter();`. En cuanto a pasarlo a variables independientes, no tiene mucho sentido, tendrias que saber cuantas variables has definido, para eso mantener un array seria lo mas optimo)

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una función para validar los formatos de fecha, seria cuestio que recorrieras el array y cada elemento lo validaras para saber si el formato es o no de una fecha valida.

```
    $elemento='2012-02-28 12:12:12';

if (validateDate($elemento)){
    echo 'Es fecha';
} else {
    echo 'NO Es fecha';
}

function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

Espero que te sirva el ejemplo.